# Getting a page's HTML source using cURL procudes a different output

Tags: php, curl, vk

I'm doing some 'Tests' to get videos links from video sharing websites. VK is really famous for this, therefore i tried to 'extract' the videos links from inspecting the source code and looking for `mp4` in the search.

Using Inspect elemnt i was able to get a vaild, working download link, as the following:

```
https:\/\/cs640504.userapi.com\/2\/u10937371\/videos\/15042b2c33.720.mp4?extra=3FJ6b3vkVbBynpLZlQ6BIt53MGw-O_818RMkuXi8Th8_fcMp36yJ9X0L46a7kgWHVRroR_SBPXv11pHj0FZ1VDx1U3TI8bVg_q5PfKUeafsuVUGrftk3n5jSqrL0jWXPvfsUJelAsCslrg
```

Furthermore, i've tried to make an API in php for it, my code is:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $id);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0)     Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0");
$data= curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $data;
```

The output from the script was pretty different, as i think its because the request data (user agent.. and so on), why? because i had this outputed link:

```
https:\/\/cs640504.userapi.com\/2\/u10937371\/videos\/f8d21266d2.720.mp4?extra=usTgnC2N531TgOLHogKfbqugvi8Bm6GWpC7qPhE45-Q31GcaXzN6ni3ek47D0S1FfrV4hgvhrUnAp-16iUHl1CJUVqegstNr3yzKkDWtaYu2pSmf9YsC1uMQUt_hBw
```

The problem is, it's not vaild and working, it redirects me to a 404 error page. I have no idea why, even the file id `f8d` is different, while `IDM` and VK video downloading services give me as the first example, my script produces the second output (invalid).

Any ideas why?